# Shopping Cart Rule Causing Internal Sever Error 500

Tags: error, shopping-cart-price-rules, ce-1.9.1.0, addtocart

I am trying to configure a shopping cart price rule where if you add 2 or more bundled products from one category you get the discount off the subtotal of the cart. This is the only cart rule on the website. I have it as follows.

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

```
If total quantity  equals or greater than  2  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions:
    Category  is  18
```

Actions:  Fixed Amount discount for whole cart. 
Discount Amount: $29.00

This seems like a straight forward discount, and it DOES apply to the correct products in the cart.

The problem arrises when you try and add a configured product to the cart, I am getting a "Internal Server Error 500".   After checking with the hosting company they reported that it is attempting to use a truly massive amount of memory, and even when we allowed it to use ten times a normally allowable amount it still failed. Here is a slow log of the php process erroring out:

[0x000000000df1e2f8] __call() /chroot/home/shopadip/shopadiplayer.com/html/lib/Varien/Object.php:631

[0x00007fffa1344f80] __call() unknown:0

[0x000000000df1e0c8] getOperator() 
/chroot/home/shopadip/shopadiplayer.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Condition/Abstract.php:297

[0x000000000df1d358] isArrayOperatorType() /chroot/home/shopadip/shopadiplayer.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Condition/Abstract.php:557

[0x000000000df1c0c0] validateAttribute() /chroot/home/shopadip/shopadiplayer.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Condition/Product/Abstract.php:523

[0x000000000df1bbe8] validate() /chroot/home/shopadip/shopadiplayer.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php:70

[0x000000000df1b730] validate() /chroot/home/shopadip/shopadiplayer.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Condition/Combine.php:307

[0x000000000df1b1e8] validate() /chroot/home/shopadip/shopadiplayer.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product/Combine.php:216

[0x000000000df1adb8] validate() 
/chroot/home/shopadip/shopadiplayer.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product/Combine.php:216

[0x000000000df1adb8] validate() /chroot/home/shopadip/shopadiplayer.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product/Subselect.php:117

[0x000000000df1a870] validate() /chroot/home/shopadip/shopadiplayer.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product/Combine.php:219

When I turn the shopping cart rule to inactive, all products are added to the cart without error.  I cannot find any threads about server errors when using cart rules. Please help.

Magento CE 1.9.1

Thanks,

Comment: Hopefully doing this should fix it: http://ka.lpe.sh/2015/03/28/magento-checkout-cart-500-error/

Comment: Thanks for the article @Kalpesh!  That seemed to get rid of the redirect loop and also has my discounts working across the board!

Answer (score 3):

Based on comments on @kalpesh link this also solved the problem for me. (adding the fix here for future reference)

There is a patch for this
https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/54529dadb0bc01a62a2d

It is marked for EE but the fix worked for us.

app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product/Subselect.php

```
- if (parent::validate($item)) {
+ if (Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Combine::validate($item)) {
```

Comment: This patch works well on Magento 1.9.2.4 CE too, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A similar problem - conflict between a shopping cart price rule and adding / amending configurable parts to the shopping cart has been tracked back (by SimpleServers - hosts in this case) to a PHP bug.

## 193 0x00000000008981e0 in execute ()

## 194 0x00000000008a4a75 in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC ()

**Suggested resolution was to either 
- upgrade from PHP 5.4.37 to 5.5, or
- change the PHP code**

Currently haven't done either so can't comment on what works

Comment: Hahaha oh my. "change the php code". Classic. I've run into the same problem, will try it on PHP 5.5 today hopefully.

Comment: I don't recommend this. This is not a PHP bug but rather a bug in Magento core. I suggest following my recent blog post to fix this issue: http://ka.lpe.sh/2015/03/28/magento-checkout-cart-500-error/